# New Page getting open inside tabs view instead of opening as new page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using tabbed view in my Ionic 2 RC0 App. When I do this.nav.push the new page is getting opened in the tab instead of opening as a new page? What am I doing wrong here?

```
export class Tab1Page {

  constructor(public nav: NavController) {
  }

  editRecord(index){
    this.nav.push(MyCustomPage, {indexoEdit: index});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to see tabs when navigating to a subpage then set `tabsHideOnSubPages` to `true` in your config. See the docs below:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/

Comment: I just want to navigate to new page altogather...how can I do that?

Comment: I am going to need more details as I am not sure what you are asking. The above code you have should navigate you to MyCustomPage. If you are navigating from a tab Component then use the Config options to specify whether the tabs are visible in the new views. If you want to navigate to a page that is not a subpage of Tabs then you could use the NavController to setRoot(MyCustomPage). Refer to NavController docs, this method will not allow you to navigate back to the tabs

Comment: It worked perfectly....the typescript did not get compiled earlier that why It didn't work earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way

```
  constructor(public nav: NavController,private app: App) {
  }

  editRecord(index){
    this.app.getRootNav().push(MyCustomPage, {indexoEdit: index});
  }
```